# How to uninstall Electron app from electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder

I develop an ElectronJs App, and I need a function that will completely uninstall the application when it is packed. How can I do that?

I  already tried with child_process and rimraf but nothing happened and I cannot just uninstall npm so can I have some help please?